# Are version control storing solutions a good option to store Medical Imaging open data?

Tags: medical, releasing-data, images, git

We are working on several [medical imaging projects](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/medical-imaging) (*i.e.*, [BreastScreening](https://breastscreening.github.io/), [MIDA](https://mida-project.github.io/), and [MIMBCD-UI](https://mimbcd-ui.github.io/)) that deals with a huge amount of data. From medical images and data at the following modalities: (1) [MammoGraphy (MG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammography) in both CranioCaudal (CC) and MedioLateral Oblique (MLO) views; (2) [UltraSound (US)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound); (3) [Magnetic Resonance Imaging (MRI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging); to (4) text; and (5) annotations. We already have formal protocols with the clinical institutions, as well as data agreements with both the National health data responsible committee and patients. Our purpose is to publicly share the presented data after scientific publication. As follows, we will show the list of our current data size.

Summarizations list of current data to store:

1. Breast Cancer Patients = ~400 cases;
2. Multi-Modality of Medical Images Dataset = ~1200 images;
3. Annotations Dataset = ~250 annotated cases;

The question is regarding how should we share this amount of information. Our first thought was to store it on a version control storing solution, such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), for instance.

So we do the following question:

**Are version control storing solutions a good option to store Medical Imaging open data?**

Comment: I would argue no.  If you simply want to release the data with a version attached to it, I would suggest something like https://zenodo.org/.  Anytime you modify the data, just upload a new version.  Version control tools designed for code repositories are generally better used for sets of text files that are more frequently modified by distributed collaborators than large datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather suggest trying the open science framework (https://osf.io), as the above is one of their claimed aims.

Comment: Can you please state some *pros-and-cons* of your answering solution? It would be a great addon for your final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even github enterprise has a [100 GB hard limit](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/user/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files). I'd consider Amazon S3 as an alternative, especially because they price based on options for how often the data is accessed and also provides very granular user access facilities. There's a [cost calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)